# Move axis labels in between plot and facet strip

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid

I am trying to move the facet strip to the far left of my plot, so that the labels sit adjacent to the bars, and the grouping strips sit to their left (see my example below).

I assume this must be done with Grobs, but I have little experience with that level of manipulation and would appreciate guidance.

Data:

```
structure(list(dept = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Distribution Centre Services", "IT", 
"Marketing", "Merchandise & Inventory", "Operations and Communication"
), class = "factor"), label = c("test 25", "test 23", "test 24", 
"test 27", "test 26", "test 28", "test 29", "test 31", "test 33", 
"test 30", "test 32", "test 38", "test 36", "test 37", "test 43", 
"test 34", "test 35", "test 40", "test 39", "test 42", "test 41", 
"test 25", "test 23", "test 24", "test 27", "test 26", "test 28", 
"test 29", "test 31", "test 33", "test 30", "test 32", "test 38", 
"test 36", "test 37", "test 43", "test 34", "test 35", "test 40", 
"test 39", "test 42", "test 41"), Gap = c(-0.16, -0.18, -0.21, 
-0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.31, -0.31, -0.35, -0.39, -0.42, -0.15, 
-0.15, -0.2, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.29, -0.31, -0.36, 
-0.16, -0.18, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.31, -0.31, -0.35, 
-0.39, -0.42, -0.15, -0.15, -0.2, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, 
-0.29, -0.31, -0.36), section = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), impeff = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Effectiveness", "Importance"), class = "factor"), 
    score = c(0.77, 0.79, 0.82, 0.8, 0.83, 0.9, 0.91, 0.94, 0.89, 
    0.94, 0.91, 0.82, 0.74, 0.78, 0.81, 0.83, 0.85, 0.82, 0.81, 
    0.8, 0.83, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.58, 0.56, 0.61, 0.6, 0.63, 
    0.54, 0.55, 0.49, 0.67, 0.59, 0.58, 0.6, 0.61, 0.58, 0.53, 
    0.52, 0.49, 0.47)), .Names = c("dept", "label", "Gap", "section", 
"impeff", "score"), row.names = c(23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
curr.plot <- ggplot(data = curr.data, aes(x = label, y = score)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = impeff),stat = "identity", position = "dodge",width = .7) +
    geom_text(aes(label=percent(score),group=impeff), position= position_dodge(width=.7),vjust=.4,hjust=-.1) + 
    facet_grid(dept~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
    coord_flip()+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE,title=NULL))+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"))+
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(0,1))
```

Current output:
[image]

Desired output (shopped):
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
+ theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```